# Python dictionary merge up two dictionaries and building cumulative

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two arrays `date_IN` and `date_OUT` that contain the dates when animals come in and leave the farm. Now I want to plot the total population over time.

```
date_IN, date_OUT
26.09.1999,19.12.2006
26.09.1999,19.01.2005
26.09.1999,15.02.2007
26.09.1999,29.03.2006
...
```

I tried to first count the entries for each day, subtract the number of animals that leave the farm from the number of animals that come in and then sum up the sorted values.
But unfortunately the subtraction doesn't work.

```
date_EIN, date_AUS=np.genfromtxt("Gesamtbestand.txt",delimiter=',',unpack = True, converters={ 0: mdates.strpdate2num('%d.%m.%Y'), 1: mdates.strpdate2num('%d.%m.%Y') or 0})

c = Counter(date_EIN)
d = Counter(date_AUS)
tn_each_day = c - d

sorted_keys = sorted(tn_each_day,key=tn_each_day.get)
z = cumsum(sorted(d.values())) # or z = cumsum([d[k] for k in sorted_keys])
tn = dict(zip(sorted_keys,z))
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just to provide some help to others, `date_EIN` means `date_IN` and `data_AUS` refers to `data_OUT` (Ein and Aus are German words)

Comment: does every date_IN have a corresponding date_OUT?

Comment: do you want the total population c-d or the total population over time (d-c)/t

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot to change that. it's date_EIN and date_AUS for date_IN and date_OUT. I want to create a dictionary that contains all dates from date_IN and date_OUT with the number of animals that come in (positive number) or leave (negative number)for each day. Therefore I tried to first sum up over same dates in each array and then substract them in order to get the total number. hope its more clear now.

Comment: and no, not every date in has a corresponding date out.

Comment: Please help us to understand: The numbers in the in- and out-lists are not related, those are just animals leaving on that date (not necessarily the same animal); you want to substract the counts, and your problem probably is that the resulting `Counter` does not have any negative numbers for days when more animals are leaving than arriving, is that right?

Comment: I think part of the issue is that `Counters` don't subtract in that way.

Answer (score 3):

For brevity, let's use numbers instead of dates:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import itertools as it
>>> import operator as op
>>> ein = Counter([1,2,2,3,3])
>>> aus = Counter([1,2,3,4])
>>> delta = {k:ein.get(k,0)-aus.get(k,0) for k in set(it.chain(ein,aus))}
>>> delta
{1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: -1}
>>> sorted_dates = sorted(delta)
>>> population = dict(zip(sorted_dates, it.accumulate((delta[k] for k in sorted_dates), add)))
>>> population
{1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}
```

i.e. for each date, `population` holds the number of animals present in the farm.

e.g.

on date `1` one animal went in and one went out -> 0 farm population

on date `2` two animals went in and one went out -> 1 farm population

on date `3` two animals went in and one went out -> 2 farm population

on date `4` zero animals went in and one went out -> 1 farm population

Comment: Wouldn't you want all the numbers less than `k` (as opposed to exactly equal to `k`)?

Comment: @pzp `k` is a date among all the dates collected merging the in and out dates. What do you mean? Please explain. Thank you

Comment: You have the deltas for each "date", but if I understand the OP correctly, they want the populations for each date.

Comment: Yes, that's what it is. The delta expresses the population remaining in the farm on that date. Let me rewrite it

Comment: No, the delta represents the population change at that date. (For example, a population can never be negative, yet `delta[4]` is -1.) You need a function to calculate the population from the delta dictionary. `def population(n): return sum(v for k, v in delta.items() if k <= n)`

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting a `Counter` from another `Counter` just removes the keys that exist in both `Counters` from the first `Counter`. This is not what you are trying to do. Here's a working example:

```
from collections import Counter

def compareDates(d1, d2):
    d1, d2 = d1.split('.'), d2.split('.')
    for i in range(2,-1,-1):
        if d1[i] > d2[i]:
            return 1
        if d1[i] < d2[i]:
            return -1
    return 0


IN  = ['26.09.1999', '26.09.1999', '26.09.1999', '26.09.1999', '26.8.2008']
OUT = ['19.12.2006', '19.01.2005', '15.02.2007', '29.03.2006', '27.8.2008']

c_IN  = Counter(IN)
c_OUT = Counter(OUT)

tn_each_day  = {}

for date, count in c_IN.items():
    if date not in tn_each_day :
        tn_each_day[date] = 0
    tn_each_day[date] += count

for date, count in c_OUT.items():
    if date not in tn_each_day :
        tn_each_day [date] = 0
    tn_each_day[date] -= count

cumulative = {}
population = 0
for date in sorted(tn_each_day, cmp=compareDates):
    population += tn_each_day[date]
    cumulative[date] = population
    print '{}: {}'.format(date, population)
```

This produces an output of:

```
26.09.1999: 4
19.01.2005: 3
29.03.2006: 2
19.12.2006: 1
15.02.2007: 0
26.8.2008: 1
27.8.2008: 0
```